# Why does a function in a child view model causes a computed in the parent view model to fire?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Pushing the button in the following code does 2 things: It executes a function in a nested view model, and also makes a `computed` in the parent view model to execute.

```js
var MasterViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.nested = new FirstViewModel();
  self.func = ko.computed (function() {
    var items = self.nested.array();
    alert("executed");
  });
}
var FirstViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.array = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.push = function () {
    self.array.push(new SecondViewModel());
    alert("pushed");
  }
}

var SecondViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.z = ko.observable();
}

var mvm = new MasterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(mvm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <div data-bind="with: nested">
    <button data-bind="text: 'push me', click: push"></button>
  </div>
```

However, if the `computed` is changed to a simple function, it doesn't execute when the button is pushed. Why?

```js
var MasterViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.nested = new FirstViewModel();
  self.func = function() {
    var items = self.nested.array();
    alert("executed");
  };
}
var FirstViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.array = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.push = function () {
    self.array.push(new SecondViewModel());
    alert("pushed");
  }
}

var SecondViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.z = ko.observable();
}

var mvm = new MasterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(mvm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <div data-bind="with: nested">
    <button data-bind="text: 'push me', click: push"></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is `data-bind="func"` in `<div data-bind="func">` meant to do?

Comment: It's basically `data-bind="undefined"` because it even is `data-bind="func()"` in his 2nd attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: The `data-bind="func"` in `<div data-bind="func">` raises a red flag for me. Normally a binding is in the form `bindingName: boundValue`.

But answering the question: A computed's value is recomputed whenever any of the observables it depends on is changed. You're changing `self.array` in `FirstViewModel#push`, so naturally the value of the computed that uses it in `MasterViewModel` (as `self.nested.array`) is recomputed.

Comment: Thanks. `data-bind="func"` is a mistake, I'll edit it out

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the accepted answer, I'm posting here the relevant parts of the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html):

> **How dependency tracking works**
>
> [...]
>
> It’s actually very simple and rather lovely. The tracking algorithm
>   goes like this:
>
> 1. Whenever you declare a computed observable, KO immediately invokes its evaluator function to get its initial value.
> 2. While the evaluator function is running, KO sets up a subscription to any observables (including other computed observables) that the
>      evaluator reads. The subscription callback is set to cause the
>      evaluator to run again, looping the whole process back to step 1
>      (disposing of any old subscriptions that no longer apply).
> 3. KO notifies any subscribers about the new value of your computed observable.

If you'd like to prevent a dependency creation, use `peek`:

> Knockout’s automatic dependency tracking normally does exactly what
>   you want. But you might sometimes need to control which observables
>   will update your computed observable, especially if the computed
>   observable performs some sort of action, such as making an Ajax
>   request. The `peek` function lets you access an observable or computed
>   observable without creating a dependency.

So the given code will be changed into:

```js
var MasterViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.nested = new FirstViewModel();
  self.func = ko.computed (function() {
    var items = self.nested.array.peek();
    alert("executed");
  });
}
var FirstViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.array = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.push = function () {
    self.array.push(new SecondViewModel());
    alert("pushed");
  }
}

var SecondViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.z = ko.observable();
}

var mvm = new MasterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(mvm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <div data-bind="value: func">
     <div data-bind="with: nested">
       <button data-bind="text: 'push me', click: push"></button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Note that now, when pushing the button, only an alert of `"pushed"` is displayed.