# Why does a function in a child view model causes a function in the parent view model to fire?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is a follow-up question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844156/why-does-a-function-in-a-child-view-model-causes-a-function-in-the-parent-view-m):

On the following code, `func` is a simple function that's bounded to a parent `div`. Naturally, it fires when document loads, but it also fires when the button is pressed.

As explained on the answer to the linked question, I thought this can happen only if `func` would have been a `computed` (since it's value is recomputed whenever any of the observables it depends on is changed), but I now see it happens with a simple function.

Why?

```js
var MasterViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.nested = new FirstViewModel();
  self.func = function() {
    var items = self.nested.array();
    alert("executed");
  };
}
var FirstViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.array = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.push = function () {
    self.array.push(new SecondViewModel());
    alert("pushed");
  }
}

var SecondViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.z = ko.observable();
}

var mvm = new MasterViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(mvm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <div data-bind="value: func()">
     <div data-bind="with: nested">
       <button data-bind="text: 'push me', click: push"></button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: First thing is looks wrong - you calling executing here `<div data-bind="value: func()">`

Comment: @DanilGholtsman, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Isn't it cause first alert with "executed" message? I'm sorry for confusing you if it's expected behaviour

Comment: @DanilGholtsman, it does, but it is indeed expected. What I wasn't expecting is the call when pushing the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KO works with observables (as you know). When you provide an *expression* for a binding value rather than just a reference to an observable, KO effectively wraps that expression in a computed when applying the bindings. So this:

```
<div data-bind="value: func()"></div>
```

...is effectively the same as this:

```
<div data-bind="value: computed"></div>
```

...where KO is creating `computed` behind the scenes something like this:

```
computed = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return func();
});
```

And since `func` uses the value of the observable `self.nested.array`, KO's change tracking sees and remembers that fact when it computes the computed's value, so it knows to recompute the computed when `self.nested.array` changes.

Comment: If you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365078/if-knockout-wraps-a-bounded-function-expression-in-a-computed-why-it-doesnt-al?noredirect=1#comment85733339_49365078) follow-up question it would be great.