# Using a computed with options binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use a `computed` object together with `options` binding, but the `computed` is only called on the document load (Instead of each time the button is clicked). However, when I replace the `computed` with a simple function, it works as expected - The function is called on each item creation.

What's the reason for the difference? The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850849/3002584) made me think they should behave the same, but apparently they don't. Why, then?

Code (or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wegercvw/)):

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.toggler = false;
    self.allowedOptions = ["A", "B", "C"];
    self.availableOptions = ko.computed(function() {
      var allowedOptions = self.allowedOptions.slice();
      self.toggler = !self.toggler;
      if (self.toggler) {
        return allowedOptions.splice(2, 1);
      }
      return allowedOptions;
    });
    self.createItems = function () {
      self.items.push({});
    }
}

vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>  
   <button data-bind="text: 'create a dropdown', click: createItems"></button>
   <div data-bind="foreach: items">
      <select data-bind="options: $parent.availableOptions,
                         optionsText: $data,
                         value: $data"></select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Howe

Comment: Computeds update in response to observables changing. The values your computed uses are not observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A KO `computed` is fired the first time through and then any time an `observable` inside the `computed` changes.  You don't have `observables` in your `computed`, so it only fires the first time.

Here's your example, modified so the `computed` fires on each button click by changing an `observable` and flipping the value of `self.toggler()` in `self.createItems()`.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.toggler = ko.observable(false);
  self.availableOptions = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.toggler()) {
      return ["C"];
    }
    return ["A", "B", "C"];
  });
  self.createItems = function() {
    self.items.push({});
    self.toggler(!self.toggler());
  }
}

vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button data-bind="text: 'create a dropdown', click: createItems"></button>
  <div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <select data-bind="options: $parent.availableOptions,
                         value: $data"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update to explain more fully**

KO caches the results of a `computed` function and doesn't re-evaluate it until an `observable` inside that `computed` function changes.

Comment: Can you refer to what seems to me contradicting on the answer I linked to, where it is explained that a simple function is also wrapped in a computed, and thus should also fire only if one of its dependencies changes (which is not what happens; it fires every time)?

Comment: @HeyJude updated answer to explain how ko.computeds are cached.